# Joomla Event Handling for controls(dropdown list etc.) and Joomla 3 reference

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

Is there a functionality for event handling in custom component development in joomla? I have searched all throughout and I only found about JEvents which was not exactly what I needed. My simple functionality is that when I select a value from 1st dropdown, a different list contents are displayed.

Also, does somebody have a complete reference for developing extensions in Joomla especially in Component Development?

I only have the Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development 3rd Edition by Tim Plummer but it only discusses the basics in component development. I have some special cases in our development that cannot be found in the book. Since Joomla! 3 is only new, there are few references and mostly from lower versions.

Comment: Did you even look at joomla.org?  There are tons of resources there...documentation, tutorials, communities.

Comment: Yes I did. I even have finished reading the articles for custom component development there. Almost all articles are incomplete.

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component) ,it may help..

Comment: ^Jobin Jose, I have finished reading that tutorial. Almost all pages for version 3.x are blank, I have been relying on version 2.5 tutorials..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chaining Controls** in a form is not a core feature. You have to introduce your own Javascript routines to conditionally show controls.

**JEvent** is oriented to support internal communication between a components and plugins.

To learn how to develop an extension, you can also check FOF:

**Developing a Joomla 3.x Component using RAD/FOF**
http://www.slideshare.net/pe7er/jduk14-developingcomponentfof